# QlikView error on nightly reload "Failed to open file in write mode for file"

Tags: qlikview

I have a nightly re-load script that has been running successfully each night for months. Every so often I note in the morning that it has failed. The error is per question title:

"Failed to open file in write mode for file XYZ..."

When I see this, I right-click the node in QMC and hit "Run". The task then completes successfully.

Today was the first exception in that on manually re-triggering the reload it actually faulted a second time with the same error. On a second manual re-trigger it completed successfully.

I have read similar questions and answers on the QlikView community forums but they don't seem to help. If it was a user permission issue, it wouldn't work when I initiate it from QMC (would it? And besides - the fault does not occur every night - the re-load succeeds on most nights). For the same reason it would appear unlikely to be a folder issue or even a script issue.

Any pointers on how to debug?

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question in the QlikView community also and there is [a response](https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-App-Development/quot-Failed-to-open-file-in-write-mode-for-file-quot-on-nightly/m-p/1588408/highlight/false#M443357) which is essentially that:

- Two tasks are trying to access the file at the same time

Investigating further, we have a second task running on an hourly schedule. The nightly task takes 1hr 45mins to complete - which means it will always overlap with one or two runs of the hourly task and, presumably, conflict occasionally.

Unfortunately the QlikView Management Console (QMC) doesn't allow hourly schedules to be set up between fixed times only (say from 2am to midnight, as opposed to 24 hours a day) so the resolution is either to set up about 22 separate daily schedules (one for 2am, one for 3am, etc) that each mimic the hourly schedule - but that looks like a maintenance and monitoring nightmare (especially as there are 11 dependent tasks that run in sequence pending success of the hourly schedule), or, another alternative is to allow it to fault occasionally and re-run during business hours.